# Can't display data in view from model in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

In my project I have orders which have many products and customers who have many orders. I am confused because I want to get all orders that a certain customer has and the products of each order. I messed up something somewhere and I am not sure if I set my relationships correctly. Here is my products table:

[image]

Here is my customers table:

[image]

And here is my orders table:

[image]

Here are my models:

Product:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');
    }
}
```

Order:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'id');
    }

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
}
```

Customer:

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'id');
    }
}
```

I get all customers from my database with `App\Customer::all()` in my CustomersController and pass the data in my customers.blade.php.

```
<h1>Customers:</h1>
    @foreach($customers as $customer)
        <h3>{{$customer->name}}</h3>
        @foreach($customer->orders as $order)
        <p>Order ID: {{$order->id}}</p>
            @foreach($order->products as $product)
            <p>Product title: {{$product->title}}</p>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
        <hr>
    @endforeach
```

Here is the output:

[image]

If someone could explain why it doesn't output everything and give some advice if this is the way to go with the relationships, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Try changing {{ }} to {!! !!}

Comment: in order model change `return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'id');` to `return $this->hasMany('App\Product');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by making a pivot table for products and orders called products_orders which holds the product_id and the order_id and making a many to many relationship between Product and Order. That is because an order may have multiple products and products may exist in multiple orders.
My pivot table products_orders:

[image]

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'products_orders');
    }

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
}
```

I made a one to many relationship (customer_id in orders table) for Customer and Order and now everything works fine.

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your products should belong to an order, rather than have a many-to-many relationship.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it but it still doesn't print all products in an order that a customer has.

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier, I've been away for a day. Didn't realise you actually needed a many-to-many relationship, but I'm glad you found the right answer yourself. :)